# Execute Statement using one value of query array

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I am attempting to execute a query using a prepared array. The array has two elements but this query uses only one of them. I am using node-postgres.

Array:

```
var g=[];
g.push(email,password);
```

Query:

```
getter.query('SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email_address = $1)',g,         
    function(err, result){
        if (err) console.log(err);
            //do stuff including another query
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`
STATEMENT: SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email_address = $1)
```

How do I Execute Statement using only one value of query array? Is there a way to get prepared query statements to accept only one or some elements of an array?

Comment: Edited, sorry thought that was clear.

Comment: `[g[0]]`? `g.slice(0, 1)`?

Comment: You want `g.push(email)` instead of `g.push(email,password)`. What's not clear is what `password` is doing there in the first place. It's not needed and it causes the failure.

Comment: Password is the second variable which is used later.

Comment: Then put it later in the array

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense but doesn't solve the general problem. I'll try it. Is there a way to get prepared query statements to accept only one or some elements of an array?